# Sorting strings by their first word, which is a number

Tags: python, sorting

**Scenario**

We all know that trying to sort numbers alphabetically ends up with things like

`123, 234, 5, 76, 9`

But let's say you have a list of strings that look something like

```
123 Some title
234 Another title
5 More title
76 Titles abound
9 Last title
```

and you want it sorted by the size of the number in the first word of each title.

**Expected result**

```
5 More title
9 Last title
76 Titles abound
123 Some title
234 Another title
```

**Question**

Is there a nice way to sort this way, either by going via a different data structure, or otherwise?

**Details**

I entertained the thought of turning into some sort of dict or associated array such as

```
5: More title,
//...
```

but the numbers aren't necessarily unique for my use-case.

Comment: Why not store a list of words at each key of your dictionary? You can used an `OrderedDict` to keep the keys in ascending order.

Comment: @CharlesDupont - I'm having trouble visualizing what you mean. So a dict where the key is just the integers 1, 2, 3... and the value is a list of the words, and then I could use a custom sort to sort numberically by the first word?

Comment: Your idea to use a dictionary seems like a good one. Since you said the numbers aren't necessarily unique, your dictionary could be something like: `{5:[first title, another title], 9: [last title], ...}` So basically you can store a list of multiple titles that have the same number to get around the non-uniqueness of the numbers.  And an `OrderedDict` is just a special case of a dictionary where you can keep all the keys in ascending order so that you can do an easy print-out or whatever when you are done parsing your input and building the dictionary.

Comment: The flagged duplicate link splits on `.`. The idea for your case would be similar. You use spaces. So you can split on the first space only and go from there. Example, if you have: `s = "123 bob is cool"`. Then doing this: `s.split(None, 1)` will give: `['123', 'bob is cool']`. Doing this can also compliment going down the path of using the dictionary solution discussed in the comments.

Comment: @idjaw - That's fine. That thread answers my question quite nicely. I tried searching for it, but that one didn't show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `lambda` in your call to the [`sorted` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted). If these are your lines read in as a list of strings:

```
lines = ['123 Some title', '234 Another title', '5 More title', '76 Titles abound', '9 Last title']

# split the string into columns by whitespace, then cast the first
# column to an integer, and use that value to sort the strings.
sorted_lines = list(sorted(lines, key=lambda x: int(x.split()[0])))
```

You can use the fact that the strings are **whitespace** delimited, and you want to sort by the first column if cast as an integer. This yields the result you desired.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary to store your titles and dict comprehension to sort them.

```
titles = {int(title.split()[0]):' '.join(title.split()[1:])for title in lst}
newTitles = {tup[0]:tup[1] for tup in sorted(titles.items())}
```

Comment: `title.split(' ')` should be: `title.split()` as `split` uses whitespace by default as a delimiter.